# How to wait for the completion of the wget and tar command?

Tags: linux, ssh, phpseclib

I have a code array similar to the one below.

```
$ssh->exec('mkdir /root/example');
$ssh->exec('wget -q -P /root http://www.example.com/example.tar.bz2');
$ssh->exec('tar -xjf /root/example.tar.bz2 -C /root/example');
$ssh->exec('rm /root/example.tar.bz2');
```

My problem;

The next command is starting before the wget and tar commands are completed. How do I wait for the completion of the wget and tar command?

**I tried;**

```
$ssh->exec('mkdir /root/example');
$ssh->exec('wget -q -P /root http://www.example.com/example.tar.bz2');
sleep(10);
$ssh->exec('tar -xjf /root/example.tar.bz2 -C /root/example');
sleep(10);
$ssh->exec('rm /root/example.tar.bz2');
```

I tried sleep command. But not work.

Edit: My english is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing `$ssh->setTimeout(0);`. phpseclib times out, by default, after 10s. Setting the timeout to 0 will make it so that phpseclib doesn't time out. PHP might but phpseclib won't.

Comment: @MehmetCanErtanLastOfDead - Doing it after the ssh login would be sufficient. The timeout gets reset to whatever you set it to after every command. eg. if you set the timeout to 30s every exec() will have a timeout of 30s. If you set it to 0 then no exec() will timeout.